# Add LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace boolean key to Info.plist XML

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I need to add `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` to Info.plist in order to make my Xamarin.IOS app's downloaded files appear in the Files apps.

In the Visual Studio Info.plist editor, there doesn't seem to be a place to add keys, so I'm editing the file directly, and I'm not sure of the format. If I create a key with type of `<boolean>` then I get an error when opening the file again in VS.

This is my attempt that doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't seem to have any affect when running the app in  iPhoneSimulator:

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

Is the correct way to add a boolean key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are two ways to add key-value in info.plist .

1.Open with [image] ,add the key-value at the end of the root `dict` element .

```
 <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
 <true/>
```

[image]

---

2.Open with [image] , click the button [image] at the end ,and add a Boolean key .

[image]