# Access to the path '/var/root/HandSAppPdf' is denied

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created a xamarin.forms project in which I am using PCL STORAGE to interact with the internal storage of the phone device. On Android it is working fine, it's creating a folder on the internal storage and then a pdf file in that folder.

I want to achieve the same thing on iOS too. But it's throwing this exception. kindly help me out. much appriciated.

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            await PCLReportGenaratePdf("/var/root/");
        }
        else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            await PCLReportGenaratePdf("/storage/emulated/0/");
        }
        
    }
    private async Task PCLReportGenaratePdf(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<StoragePermission>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                //if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
                    status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<StoragePermission>();
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
                IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("HandSAppPdf", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Hello.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            }
            else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                //permission denied
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Something went wrong
        }


    }
```

Comment: please show us the code that generates the error

Comment: Jason, I have updated the question along with the code.

Comment: it's throwing the exception on the following line.
 
`'IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("HandSAppPdf", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);`

Comment: is `path` set to `/var/root`?

Comment: yes, in the case of the iOS platform `path` of the root directory is `/var/root`

Comment: Didn’t you have it set to the AppData enum originally?  /var/root is not a user accesible folder

Comment: yes, but it's the requirement to create the report in the root folder.

or will the user be able to access the pdf report from AppData?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to access it from outside of the app?

Comment: yes. that's right. Once the user has generated the pdf report from inside the app. The user should be able to access it from outside the app on the mobile device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517856/add-lssupportsopeningdocumentsinplace-boolean-key-to-info-plist-xml